# Cleaning HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-parsing

In an application I am developing, the user enters HTML in a text box, to edit an element on his page. At this stage, the user can add any sort of content, even broken HTML, and some text nodes.

To make sure I get somewhat clean code, I do this

```
var s = document.createElement('div');
s.innerHTML = content;
// loop over each node in s, and if text node is found, wrap in span.
content = s.innerHTML
```

The problem with this snippet is that is the content was a `<TD>Text</TD>`, the result I get is `Text`, since there cannot be a `TD` in a `DIV`.

Is there a fix to get valid content, in all cases?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with doing it using the DOM is that you don't really want fully corrected html, because you are adding the condition that the html is allowed to be a snippet. You want some malformed html corrected, and some not.

Googling a bit threw up this jQuery plugin : http://www.davidpirek.com/blog/html-beautifier-jquery-plugin

but I can't vouch for it.

I would probably agree with Graham and suggest HTML Tidy since it's mature and fast even if you have to wait for the response.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to pass your HTML string to a server page running [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) which would then return the 'clean' version. I'm not aware of any robust, client-side only solutions I'm afraid.

EDIT: one cheap solution is to use the DOM itself, or even quicker with jQuery:

```
var input='<div><td>foo</td>';
var output = $('<div>'+html+'</div>').html(); //=> '<div>foo</div>'
```

This won't clean up all errors, but might be enough for you.